# Detecting a bundle in Symfony's AppKernel

Tags: php, symfony, exception

In my Symfony 2 project I have a bundle which handles API requests to my website. If an error is generated from within that bundle, I'd like to return a JSON formatted response.

This is how I'm currently doing it:

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $controller = $event->getRequest()->get('_controller');

    if (substr($controller, 0, 25) === 'MyProject\Bundle\MyBundle')) {
        $event->setResponse(new JsonResponse(
            ['error' => 'An unknown error has occurred.'],
            500
        ));
    }
}
```

It feels like I might be approaching this the wrong way. Is there a better method for detecting the bundle from where the error originated?